# kNN Classifier - importance of DataFrame column order - is this a scikit bug, pandas bug or by design?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

We have this sci-py code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

df = pd.DataFrame({'Category':['X','X','X','X','X','X','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y']
                        ,'Age':[10,20,30,35,32,33,27,70,40,50,60]
                        ,'Weight':[15,16,21,33,7,8,9,11,31,38,25]
                        ,'Exercise':[2,0,0,1,7,6,9,11,2,0,5]})

classifier_3NN = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, metric='minkowski')

train_df = df[['Age','Weight','Exercise']]
target_ss = df['Category']

classifier_3NN.fit(train_df, target_ss)

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[11,27,39]
                        ,'Weight':[21,9,36]
                        ,'Exercise':[7,6,0]})
```

Intuitively we would expect to be able to feed the test data into the classifier in any order of the columns of its dataframe and the algorithm will take acount of the column headers but we are getting the following:

```
In [21]: classifier_3NN.predict(test_df[['Age','Weight','Exercise']])

Out[21]: array(['X', 'X', 'Y'], dtype=object)
```

When I swap the ordering:

```
In [22]: classifier_3NN.predict(test_df[['Exercise','Weight', 'Age']])

Out[22]: array(['X', 'X', 'X'], dtype=object)
```

Is this by design or a bug? If it's a bug then where is the bug happening - which package? If it is by design then where is it documented?

Comment: I don't think sklearn supports pandas. The reason they work together is that dataframes are wrappers for numpy arrays. By passing `test_df[['Age','Weight','Exercise']]` and `test_df[['Exercise','Weight', 'Age']]` you are actually passing two different arrays. In the second one, sklearn will take Exercise values as Age values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a bug, but I agree it could be better documented. You have to provide the dataframe in the correct order.

As scikit was built with numpy in mind the Dataframe is converted to a numpy 2d array (this also during the `fit` part), and it does not save the headers order.

The array is checked and converted before proceeding with the algorithm, through `check_array`, in which if there are no problems with the dtypes it basically returns `numpy.array(thedataframe)`.

This happens in the [utils.validation module](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/06bf797c0deabe2a2f166d19abbd0c305da4d123/sklearn/utils/validation.py).

Answer (score 1):

It would work fine if you called `.fit()` again changing the order of the labels as well.

SKLearn classifiers don't keep track of headers at all.